# Data conversion from a Text file to SQL

Tags: c#, ssis

[I need to insert the data into a SQl database using SSIS or C#.
Could somebody provide some help to transform the data into a
SQL table. Please CLICK HERE to see the current data layout and the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKNye.jpg)

Comment: Please click on the blue text to see the current data and the desired state

Comment: Please click on this blue text [ask] to read about how questions should be asked, and also this one [Tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking us to provide you some code. You haven't even tried yet.

Use a filereader, add each line to a string. Add the string to your database with executescalar or ExecuteNonquery or something.

If you gave us some code it would be easier to help you. Right now, I can't do anything. Google the functions I told you and you will find enough topics with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two solution I been trying

Solution 1:

```
//Create Connection to SQL Server
SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection();
SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog =TechBrothersIT; " + "Integrated Security=true;";

System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(SourceFolder+SourceFileName);

string line = "";
Int32 counter = 0;

SQLConnection.Open();

while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //skip the header row
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        //prepare insert query
        string query = "Insert into " + TableName +
                       " Values ('" + line.Replace(filedelimiter, "','") + "')";

       //execute sqlcommand to insert record
       SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection);
       myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   counter++;
}

SourceFile.Close();
SQLConnection.Close();

//Move the file to Archive folder
File.Move(SourceFolder+SourceFileName, ArchiveFodler + SourceFileName);
```

Solution 2:

I originally solved this with an Excel query:

```
Sub Transpone()
a = 1
   `enter code here` b = 8
    Do    ' Bucle externo.
    Do While Contador < 65000
        Contador = Contador + 1
        If Range("A" & a) <> "" Then
    Range("A" & a & ":A" & b).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Converted").Select
    k = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    `enter code here`Range("A" & k).Select
    `enter code here`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Identification").Select
    a = a + 8
    b = b + 8
        Else
    Comprobar = False
       Exit Do
        End If
       Loop
     Loop Until Comprobar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

It can be very easily done in SSIS.
The below metioned link can help you.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/philoj/2007/11/10/transposing-rows-and-columns-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: I am using this script to reas the rows from the text file. This allows me to read groups of 6 rows each time.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SSIS-script task, to read the rows from the text file. This allows me to read groups of 6 rows each loop. 
The variables are taken into a  SQL task which contain an insert. I need some assistance since it is inserting all the text rows on the same SQL row, it is not appending, below you'll see the insert satement.

public void Main()
        {

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QBDQ35H; Initial Catalog=TensorFacts; Integrated Security=True");
        int counter = 0;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Imagine processing\\output.txt");
        string[] large = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Imagine processing\\output.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < large.Length; i += 6)

        {

            Dts.Variables["User::imageName"].Value = (string)large[i];
            Dts.Variables["User::bestGuess"].Value = (string)large[i + 1];
            Dts.Variables["User::secondGuess"].Value = (string)large[i + 2];
            Dts.Variables["User::thirdGuess"].Value = (string)large[i + 3];
            Dts.Variables["User::fourthGuess"].Value = (string)large[i + 4];
            Dts.Variables["User::fifthGuess"].Value = (string)large[i + 5];

            //string line0 = large[i];
            //string line1 = large[i + 1];
            //string line2 = large[i + 2];
            //string line3 = large[i + 3];
            //string line4 = large[i + 4];
            //string line5 = large[i + 5];


            //MessageBox.Show(line0 + '\n' + line1 + '\n' + line2 + '\n' + line3 + '\n' + line4 + '\n' + line5 + '\n');

            //counter++;
        }
    }
```

THEN IN SSIS "EXECUTE SQL taks"
INSERT INTO dbo.scores (imageName, bestGuess, firstScore,firsTag, secondGuess,secondScore, secondTag, thirdGuess,thirdScore,thirdTag,fourthGuess, fourthScore, fourthTag,fifthGuess,fifthScore, fifthTag) VALUES (?,?,0,0,?,0,0,?,0,0,?,0,0,?,0,0)